# Associate elastic ip address to instance via user-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, user-data, elastic-ip

I'm trying to associate an elastic IP address to instance via the user-data using the AWS cli

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
REGION=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .region)
aws ec2 associate-address --region "$REGION" --instance-id "$INSTANCE_ID" --public-ip *.*.*.*
```

This user-data is set in launch configuration for auto scaling group that set to running only 1 instance

Any idea why i can't associate elastic IP via the user-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an ec2 classic instance, or an  instance in a VPC? (Unless you have a very old account, it is probably not an ec2 classic instance)

The command you are using is for assocating an elastic ip address for a ec2-classic instance. If you are in a VPC it would be more like:

```
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id "$INSTANCE_ID" --AllocationId=eipalloc-xxxxxx
```

Comment: Yes, my instance is in a VPC.
Thanks!